# Android WebView doesn't shows some characters "ṭ ḍ ḥ"

Tags: android, encoding, webview, latin

Some of the not-show characters:

&#7693; - ḍ
&#7717; - ḥ
&#7723; - ḫ
&#7731; - ḳ

All the characters that not shown in Android WebView, HTML Entity's are greater than 7000.

I tried the solution below but it didn't work.

```
    WebSettings settings = myWebView.getSettings();
    settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "#ḍḥḳ#", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

It showed in WebView :  "   "

I'll be very thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Using entities for such symbols isn't best idea at all.

You should use UTF-8, which can hold virtually any character. For solution, you've showed (that doesn't seem to work) -- make yourself sure, that either document content or string, you're passing is actually encoded in UTF-8. It's not just setting the encoding, but actually encoding correctly the file as well.

And don't mix up entities with UTF-8. Either use one or another solution to encode special characters.